# What is the difference between personal statement and statement of purpose?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, professorship, statement-of-purpose

I am planning to apply for a Ph.D. program in the USA. Some universities ask for personal statement whereas some for a statement of purpose. What is the main difference?

Comment: I don't know the answer since I'm not from the US, but I don't understand why you were downvoted so I upvoted back